# How to increase maxclients on Xvnc

Tags: x11, vnc, x11vnc, tigervnc

I'm running a headless VNC server (TigerVNC with Xfce). I need to increase the maximum allowed number of X clients because I'm hitting the 256 limit (yes I've got that many) and I get the *"Maximum number of clients reached"* error.

I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515786/280061) that you can increase it either with the `-maxclients` option on the xserver or with the appropriate configuration in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-maxclients.conf`. I don't think that applies to VNC though and I couldn't find any similar option for the vncserver command.

I tried to pass the `-maxclients 512` option to startxfce4 in `~/.vnc/xstartup` but it is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I actually *tried* the `-maxclients` option and... it worked!

It has to go on the `vncserver` command though, not on the window manager or in some X config file.

When started manually:

```
vncserver :1 -maxclients 512
```

When started via init.d:

```
update-rc.d vncserver defaults
vi /etc/default/vncservers
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-maxclients 512"
```